# How can we say two algebraic expressions are "equal" if one is undefined at certain points and the other isn't?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to understand why it is that we can say $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)} = x+1$ but then have it also be the case that the two functions $f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $g(x)=x+1$ are not equal, since $f$ is undefined when $x=1$.

That is, if it is true that $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} = x+1$ then why can we not just simplify and say that $f(x)=x+1$ so that $f(1) = (1) + 1 = 2$ ?

Comment: The definition of function clears this up. Do you know it?

Comment: We say those two expressions are equal for $x\ne1$. But it is true that they both tend to $2$ as $x\to1$, so it is possible to assign the value of that limit to $f(1)$. See [removable discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity).

Comment: They are equal also if we extend $f$ continuously at 1, i.e. we define $f(1):=\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$. Note that this is the only way to define $f$ at $1$ such that it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of these kinds of issues clear up if we go that extra step by making our assumptions clear. For example:

> Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \neq 1$. Then:
>
> $$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=x+1$$
>
> Hence, the following functions are equal.
>
> $$x \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}) \mapsto \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} \in \mathbb{R} \qquad x \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}) \mapsto x+1 \in \mathbb{R}$$

(Please comment if you do not know what this notation means.)

As you can no doubt see, this is a little messy. A sleek modern way to avoid this messiness is by working syntactically; we view rational expressions, not as functions, but as elements of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, which consists of equivalence classes of formal expressions, and forms a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) in its own right. See also, [polynomial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) and [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions). If you've never seen these ideas before, the wikipedia articles probably won't make a lot of sense, so maybe try googling for some PDF's, or take a look on youtube. Keep at it till you "get" it! Try to understand the following terms, in this order:

1. Commutative ring (with unity, although this is often left implicit)
2. Field
3. Polynomial ring and the notation $\mathbb{Q}[x]$
4. Field of fractions and the notation $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

By the way, the "solution" to this messiness mentioned in Rory Daulton's answer *could* perhaps be made to work, but as its given, it really doesn't. I quote:

> However, the Precalculus book I recently taught from (Precalculus from
>   Glencoe McGraw Hill) defines an identity as an equality where for both
>   sides the domains are equal except for finitely many values of $x$ and
>   the sides are equal when both sides are defined.

The problem is that, for example, $x=x$ is a true under this definition, but $xyy^{-1}=x$ is not, since the left-hand-side is ill-defined for infinitely many points $(x,y)$. Contrast this with what happens in $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$, where both $x=x$ and $xyy^{-1}=x$ are genuinely true. Nonetheless, I think a variant on this idea could be made to work; please comment, dear reader, if you have any thoughts on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In function theory, we say that functions $f$ and $g$ are equal if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ and *the domains of $f$ and $g$ are equal*.

However, the Precalculus book I recently taught from (*Precalculus* from Glencoe McGraw Hill) defines an identity as an equality where for both sides *the domains are equal except for finitely many values of $x$* and the sides are equal when both sides are defined.

So in the function sense, $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$ is not true, but in the Precalculus sense that is indeed an identity. The strict definition of "equality" depends on the context. This inconsistency is probably allowed so trigonometry identities can be allowed without bothering students at that stage with the details of domains.

Comment: As Git Gud said above, it was helpful for me to look at a more formal definition of "function", and what it means for two functions to be equal. I looked in a book called "Mathematical Thinking and Writing: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" (Randall Maddox, 2002) which states: _"Two functions f and g are said to be equal if they have the same domain and codomain, and f (a) = g(a) for all a in the domain."_ (which is pretty much identical to Rory's definition above). Anyways, thanks to everyone who commented here. I gained a lot of insight from all of your comments.

Comment: What threw me off, I suppose, is that in pre-calculus when you are practicing factoring and other techniques for simplifying algebraic expressions, you simply say $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} = x+1$ without qualification. But like you said, it depends on the context what is meant by '$=$'. I was just conflating the "equals" in the pre-calculus sense with the "equals" for functions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$.  The domain of $f(x)$ is $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{1\}$.

Actually, $$\frac{x^2 -1}{x-1} = x+1,$$ for all $x \neq 1$.

Hence, $f(x) \neq x+1$, because $1$ is in the domain of $x+1$.

Comment: The issue, as Alex points out, is not that the equations are not equivalent on the original domain, it is that we tend to suppress writing the domain of our variables because it usually doesn't convey enough useful information to be worth the space it took to write.  If, at some step in a proof, you get confused regarding the domain, that suggests it was probably a good place for the author to helpfully write the domain on that line.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=x+1$$ if $x \ne 1$